# Changing TextView from different class

Tags: java, android

I want to update TextView from another class which is not an activity, but the app keeps crushing.. 
I hope you can help

This is the class where I want to update text after knowing game result

```
  public class GameLogic {
    ...
    public void gameResult() {
            OnePlayerGameActivity gameActivity = new OnePlayerGameActivity();
            TextView result = (TextView) gameActivity.findViewById(R.id.game_result_textView);

            getPlayerChoice();

            int computer = computerChoice();

            if (mPlayerChoice == computer) {
                mPlayerStat += 0;
                mOpponentChoice += 0;
            } else if (mPlayerChoice == 1) { //ROCK
                switch (computer) {
                    case 1: //ROCK

                        break;
                    case 2:  //PAPER
                        mOpponentStat ++;
                        result.setText("LOST");
                        break;
    ...
```

all code can be found on my [GitHub](http://mattypalkahttps://github.com/MattyPalka/rock-paper-scissors-lizzard-spock-android)

Comment: Please learn Android basics ... do you really think that Activity created with `OnePlayerGameActivity gameActivity = new OnePlayerGameActivity();` would work?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating just a dummy instance of your activity which has no relation with the one in memory, instead pass the activity instance using

```
// in your OnePlayerGameActivity.java
// inside some method
GameLogic obj = new GameLogic (); // instance of GameLogic for demo
obj.gameResult(OnePlayerGameActivity.this); // pass instance
```

and change the methods signature as

```
 public void gameResult(OnePlayerGameActivity gameActivity ) {
            TextView result = (TextView) gameActivity.findViewById(R.id.game_result_textView);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That helped. I had the instance of GameLogic in OnePlayerActivity, but I didn't thought about passing the context!

Comment: @MateuszPałka yeah, that is just for the demo and i am glad that i could help, happy codung